# django view redirects to URL it shouldn't

Tags: django

I have the following view

```
def edit_booking(request, pk=None):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Http404

    agent = Agent.objects.get(user=request.user)
    booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, pk=pk)

    form = BookingForm(request.POST or None, instance=booking)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    elif form.errors:
        messages.error(request,"There was a problem, please try again")

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request,'booking_form.html', context)
```

I use the following `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^booking/create', create_booking, name="create-booking"),
    url(r'^booking/$', booking_list, name="booking-list"),
    url(r'^booking/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', booking_detail, name="booking-detail"),
    url(r'^booking/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit', edit_booking, name="edit-booking"),
]
```

For some reason when I try to submit the form after editing some booking (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/booking/24/edit) I am automatically redirected to (http://127.0.0.1:8000/booking/24/).

As far as I can tell django is not processing any further code in the view. I tried to figure out with simple print("something") to see where in the code it ends up but it just goes to the url right away as soon as I submit from the template. For completeness sake this is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset 3">
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

".", which you used as the action of the form, is interpreted by browsers as "the base of the current path directory". Since you have not used a trailing slash in your /edit URL, the browser submits the form to the nearest base, ie /booking/24.

You should always use a trailing slash:

```
url(r'^booking/create/$', create_booking, name="create-booking"),
url(r'^booking/$', booking_list, name="booking-list"),
url(r'^booking/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', booking_detail, name="booking-detail"),
url(r'^booking/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', edit_booking, name="edit-booking"),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the request method otherwise it will redirect on initial form rendering because django uses the same view for initial rendering and submitting the form.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())       
    elif form.errors:
        messages.error(request,"There was a problem, please try again")
else:
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request,'booking_form.html', context)
```